# Django-respondive-images dosen't find files when not in local

Tags: django, responsive-images

i use responsive-images https://pypi.org/project/django-responsive-images/
on my PC django works well and also django-responsive-images when i move all up to my website responsive images dosen't find images

in my template file if i use

```
<img class="card-img-top" srcset="{% srcset item.img 200x400 400x800 nocrop %}"
            src="{% src item.img 400x800 nocrop %}" alt="Card image cap">
```

i get that error it seems dosen't find file

```
FileNotFoundError at /
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/code/uploads\\Item\\0\\817_img.jpg'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://www.mysite.it/
Django Version: 3.2.5
Exception Type: FileNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/code/uploads\\Item\\0\\817_img.jpg'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py, line 238, in _open
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.4
Python Path:    
['/code',
 '/usr/local/lib/python39.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 25 Jan 2022 14:16:46 +0000
```

but if i don't use responsive images it works

```
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{item.img.url}}" alt="Card image cap">
```

do you know why it dosen't work?

Answer (score 0):

ok i found a solution, maybe is a bug for django-responsive-images

on some OS there is no problem if image path inside database is:

`media\images\myimage.jpg`

or

`media/images/myimage.jpg`

but in other OS ( like unix in raspberry pi ) django-responsive-images works only if path is with `/` so when it try to modify/copy an image he founds it
(instead on Windows a path `/` is same as `\` )

note: for Browsers there is no difference for :`<img src="media\images\myimage.jpg">` and `<img src="media/images/myimage.jpg">`

so in a template if image.path have wrong slashes like `media\images\myimage.jpg` on unix/raspberrypi only works [1] img tag, instead on windows both works

```
[1]<img src="{{item.img.url}}">
[2]<img src="{% src item.img 150x300 nocrop %}">
```